# Gradle failing to download distribution behind company proxy

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, proxy

Trying to get Jenkins behind my corp proxy to build my java library project and it keeps timing out during download of the distribution. I've followed many guides on trying to get gradle to utilize proxy settings in the `gradle.properties` file build it doesn't seem to work. I know the proxyHost and proxyPort is correct. Is there something that I'm overlooking or is it a different issue other than the proxy?

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

def baseVersion = "1.0"
def jenkinsBuildNumber = System.getenv('BUILD_NUMBER')
version = jenkinsBuildNumber != null ? baseVersion + "." + jenkinsBuildNumber : baseVersion

println 'Version: ' + version

group = 'com.company.MyLibrary'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'groovy'

jar {
    from "LICENSE.md"
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.google.guava:guava:19.0"
    compile "junit:junit:4.12"
    compile "org.assertj:assertj-core:3.2.0"
    compile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.0.31-beta"
    compile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.2"
    compile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.2"
    testCompile "com.google.guava:guava:19.0"
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
    testCompile "org.assertj:assertj-core:3.2.0"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.0.31-beta"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.2"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.2"
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    dependsOn classes
    classifier 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
    archives javadocJar
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.10'
    distributionUrl = "http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-${gradleVersion}-all.zip"
}
```

**gradle.properties**

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxy.company.net
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8989
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy.company.net
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8989
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.company.com|localhost
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

**Jenkins console output**

```
20:45:09 Started by an SCM change
20:45:09 [EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
20:45:09 Building on master in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MyLibrary
20:45:09 [WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
20:45:09 [WS-CLEANUP] Done
20:45:09 Cloning the remote Git repository
20:45:09 Cloning repository ssh://git@git.company.net/~jon/MyLibrary.git
20:45:09  > git init /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MyLibrary # timeout=10
20:45:09 Fetching upstream changes from ssh://git@git.company.net/~jon/MyLibrary.git
20:45:09  > git --version # timeout=10
20:45:09  > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress ssh://git@git.company.net/~jon/MyLibrary.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
20:45:10  > git config remote.origin.url ssh://git@git.company.net/~jon/MyLibrary.git # timeout=10
20:45:10  > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
20:45:10  > git config remote.origin.url ssh://git@git.company.net/~jon/MyLibrary.git # timeout=10
20:45:10 Fetching upstream changes from ssh://git@git.company.net/~jon/MyLibrary.git
20:45:10  > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress ssh://git@git.company.net/~jon/MyLibrary.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
20:45:11 Seen branch in repository origin/master
20:45:11 Seen 1 remote branch
20:45:11 Checking out Revision 2ece1927e5fb1d368aba28a107f6fe2c2accb9fa (origin/master)
20:45:11  > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
20:45:11  > git checkout -f 2ece1927e5fb1d368aba28a107f6fe2c2accb9fa
20:45:11  > git rev-list 66fe56731f935be83c91e38ced426aea7bba0b8f # timeout=10
20:45:11 [EnvInject] - Injecting environment variables from a build step.
20:45:11 [Gradle] - Launching build.
20:45:11 [MyLibrary] $ /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MyLibrary/gradlew -Dcommit=master clean test
20:45:11 Downloading http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
20:47:18 
20:47:18 Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
20:47:18    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
20:47:18    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
20:47:18    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
20:47:18    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
20:47:18    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
20:47:18    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
20:47:18    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
20:47:18    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
20:47:18    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
20:47:18    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
20:47:18    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
20:47:18    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
20:47:18    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1175)
20:47:18    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1123)
20:47:18    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:998)
20:47:18    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
20:47:18    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1512)
20:47:18    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
20:47:18    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
20:47:18    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
20:47:18    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
20:47:18    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
20:47:18    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
20:47:18    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
20:47:18    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
20:47:18    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
20:47:18 Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to FAILURE
20:47:18 Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
20:47:18 Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Does your corp proxy use authentication?

Comment: no it doesn't, good thought though, the gradle scripts work on my machine and the jenkins server is within the same vlan network

Comment: Are you certain the jenkins host can reach the general internet? I would try some curls or wgets from the server.

Comment: i can wget the gradle-2.10-all.zip distribution just fine when ssh'd into the server...

Comment: the gradle distro does take some time to download, is there a timeout setting in jenkins or the gradle task that is causing it to fail? I see a Build Environment > Time-out strategy in the Jenkins config, but that is set to 15 minutes which should be plenty of time

Comment: Gradle definitely expects the delay, even shows a "progress meter" made up of dots. I'm stumped. Can you try wget as the jenkins user? Also, `gradle.properties` is checked into source right?

Comment: yeah, i did wget on the gradle distro as the jenkins user and the root user, both were successful... I also did a ./gradlew clean build as jenkins user and got the same result as the jenkins console output..... and yeah, gradle.properties is in git. i'm stumped as well =\

Comment: For lack of better options, I would try: `gradlew -Dhttp.proxyHost=xxx -Dhttp.proxyPort=xxx -Dhttps.proxyHost=xxx -Dhttps.proxyPort=xxx` just to rule out that `gradle.properties` is not being applied somehow.

Comment: My issue was related to wrongly put http/https prefix:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109325/gradle-installation-having-a-proxy-issue/44260798#answer-44260797

Answer (score 25, accepted):

My solution was to update my global `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file with the correct proxy settings:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxy.company.net
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8181
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy.company.net
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8181
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.company.com|localhost
```

this is in effect, the same as passing these as command line args to `gradlew` (`./gradlew -Dhttp.proxyHost=xxx -Dhttp.proxyPort=xxx -Dhttps.proxyHost=xxx -Dhttps.proxyPort=xxx`

Comment: IN the project repository  ?

Comment: @RajuGujarati you _could_ update the properties file in the project repo and it would work, but I'd say that wouldn't be something you would want to check into source control. I'd suggest you update the global properties file in your home directory, which for macOS is the file path I mentioned in the answer above

Comment: If disable offline mode to sync the external lib e.g. 
https://github.com/ncapdevi/FragNav

How long should we wait until be build ?  It seems Resolve dependencies 'app_debugApk' is normal behaviour..

Comment: I've created the new ~/.gradle/gradle.properties file as there was none, and finally it worked for me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked by using the following lines to the gradle.properties **application folder**

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxy.company.net 
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080 
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy.company.net 
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.company.com|localhost
```

Do not forgot to enter also your password for the proxy.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This just works for me well !

run the following command on your macOS and you'll be good to go

```
rm -rf ~/.gradle
```