# Gradle installation having a proxy issue

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, proxy, android-gradle-plugin

I'm running into issues building android projects on a server in a corporate network behind a proxy on Jenkins. Have tried with both the jenkins gradle, as well as gradlew. Below is the error message after turning on debug mode.

```
17:12:31 17:12:40.482 [INFO] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager] Parsing /opt/android/tools/package.xml

17:12:32 17:12:42.383 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
17:12:42 17:12:52.384 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
17:12:42 17:12:52.384 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
17:12:42 17:12:52.384 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.

17:12:46 17:12:55.512 [WARN] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager] Failed to connect to host: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml
17:12:46 17:12:55.513 [WARN] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager] Failed to connect to host: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
17:12:46 17:12:55.514 [WARN] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager] Failed to connect to host: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml
17:12:46 17:12:55.515 [WARN] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager] Failed to download any source lists!
17:12:46 17:12:55.516 [WARN] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager] java.net.UnknownHostException: dl.google.com
17:12:46 17:12:55.543 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
17:12:46 17:12:55.544 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

This is the contents of gradle.properties.

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy.server
systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxy.server
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
```

I have attempted passing in proxy settings with jvm flags, and tried gradle versions 3.3 to 3.5. Is there anything that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

For me the [issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2182) was the `http` prefix! If this is your case, remove `http/https` prefixes!

I had my gradle.properties like this, and was failing:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=http://squid.proxy.com
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyHost=http://squid.proxy.com
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
```

---

> Proper way to set proxy settings for gradle is:
>
> ```
> systemProp.http.proxyHost=squid.proxy.com
> systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
> systemProp.https.proxyHost=squid.proxy.com
> systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following configuration in `gradle.configuration`.These are the proxy settings needed to be configured if you are working behind proxy.

Source:
(https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy)

*And don't add 'http.// or 'https:' in `systemProp.http.proxyHost` only 'www.host.com'*
.Also comment out the `systemProp.http.proxyUser` or `proxypassword` if you don't need it to login into the proxy.

```
systemProp.proxySet=true
systemProp.http.keepAlive=true
systemProp.http.proxyHost=www.host.com
systemProp.http.proxyPort=port
systemProp.http.proxyUser=username_ifneeded
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password_needed
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=local.net|some.host.com

systemProp.https.keepAlive=true
systemProp.https.proxyHost=host
systemProp.https.proxyPort=port
systemProp.https.proxyUser=username_ifneeded
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password_ifneeded
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=local.net|some.host.com
```